# Where are the Chrome profiles saved locally?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have a copy of the Chrome data from another computer and I want to check which profiles were added. By profiles I mean Google accounts for synchronization, university accounts, etc.

[image: Picture of what I mean]

I know it has to be somewhere inside `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` but I don't know which file might store this info. I'm checking all of them with SQLiteStudio but haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

it's in the `Default`  folder. (the folder name is "Default")

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

In it, it has all the profile info and other.